# Waiting for an animation to finish before switching to another?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I am using `keyup` and `keyDown` to alternate between different animations of my game sprite. On `keyDown` the sprites switches animation based on what key is being pressed, and upon `keyUp` the sprite switches back to idle animation. It works well for smaller animations like walk  but when the animation is bit long as soon as i release the key the sprite goes back to idle animation without finishing the previous animation. How Do I implement this? I tried reading up on the animation docs of libgdx but the method `isAnimationFinished` is not what I need.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private Animation animation;
    private Animation animation2;
    private Animation animation3;
    private Animation currentAnimation;
    private float elapsedTime = 0;
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;


    int[] pos = {30,30};
    int acc = 0;
    int acc_cam = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Wolverine.txt"));
//        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet.atlas"));
//        textureAtlas2 = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet(copy).atlas"));
//        animation = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
//        animation2 = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas2.getRegions());
        animation = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.findRegions("Standing"));
        animation2 = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.findRegions("Walking"));
        animation3 = new Animation(1/15f, textureAtlas.findRegions("Attcak_Stand"));
        currentAnimation = animation;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 640, 480);


        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("Tiled_tilesheet2.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        tiledMap.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        pos[0] += acc;
        camera.translate(acc_cam,0);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
        batch.begin();

        //sprite.draw(batch);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        batch.draw(currentAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), pos[0],pos[1]);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT) {
            currentAnimation = animation2;
            if(pos[0]>320){acc_cam+=2;}
            else{acc += 2;}

        }
        else if(keycode == Input.Keys.Z){
            currentAnimation = animation3;

        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        currentAnimation = animation;
        acc_cam=0;
        acc = 0;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Animation class doesn't have a means to notify you when the current animation is done (like a callback). isAnimationFinished() does tell you if the animation *would* be finished when in PlayMode#NORMAL, which I believe your animations are set to as your constructor is not instructing them to LOOP.

Your render code always draws an animation, that is set based on key input. So that is why any current animation stops abruptly, as you're telling it to switch immediately.

I don't know what your plans for various animations (lengths, when to invoke, etc) are. You'll likely have to refactor your code to figure out which animations you want to play to completion and how this ties in with your other animations or key input strategy, and so on. A simpleton solution could be to have a "next animation" that you setup based on certain key inputs, and have your code check the current animation to see if it is finished (using isAnimationeFinished - you'd have to do this every frame). If it is finished, swap next animation into current animation. If you loop animations, you'd have to factor that into your logic, too.

Another option could be to write your own callback/listener code to tell you when an Animation has finished. Scroll down (almost at the end) of this post for some ideas: http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=179

There are likely several other options too, but all would depend on how you want to transition between your animations, and only you know that as some of your animations are very short, some long and they are changing based on the inputs you are creating in your game.